# How to set environment variables in a Jenkins Scripted Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

According to the [Jenkins docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/), this is how one sets a Global Environment Variable for a Declarative Pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'my-label'
    }
    environment {
        value = 'World'
    }
    stages {
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                sh 'echo Hello, ${value}'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is "Hello, World" as expected.

What is the correct way to do this in a **Scripted** Pipeline? The following does not error, but it does not work:

```
node('my-label') {
    environment {
        value = 'World'
    }
    stage("Test") {
        sh 'echo Hello, ${value}'
    }
}
```

The output is "Hello, ". That is not as expected.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Click *Toggle Scripted Pipeline* at this [link](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment)

Jenkinsfile (Scripted Pipeline)

```
  node {
      withEnv(['DISABLE_AUTH=true',
               'DB_ENGINE=sqlite']) {
          stage('Build') {
              sh 'printenv'
          }
      }
  }
```

Your script should look something like the following:

```
  node('my-label') {
      withEnv(['value=World']) {
           stage('Test') {
               sh 'echo Hello, ${value}'
           }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I also discovered that " env.value='World' " also works.

Answer (score 21):

In Scripted Pipelines (and in script sections of Declarative Pipelines) you can set environment variables directly via the "env" global object.

```
node {
    env.MY_VAR = 'my-value1'
}
```

You can also set variables dynamically like this:

```
node {
    def envVarName = 'MY_VAR' 
    env.setProperty(envVarName, 'my-value2')
}
```